# How to search on gerrit message piecewisely

Tags: gerrit

For example there are words like appletree and applepie in commit message,
how can I do something like

```
message:apple*
```

to find the commit that contains appletree and applepie ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `new RegExp("apple@")`. It will match all strings that start with "apple". @ means the same as .*.

or

Quoting is accepted as either double quotes (e.g. message:"the value") or as matched curly braces (e.g. message:{the value}).

Comment: Is there a way to use it in search bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions in Gerrit search adding a "^" at the beginning of the expression like in the following example:

```
path:"^report-.*[13].sh"
```

But unfortunately you only can do this with the following search operators:

- project
- repository
- branch
- intopic
- ref
- path
- file
- directory

See more info in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html)

Comment: Yes, but I need a way for searching in messages

Comment: Unfortunetly, you're out of luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit is upgraded to version 3.6 or later to support regular expression on the commit message as a condition.

e.g.  message:^.*apple.*

See more info in Gerrit documentation [Release-note](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/3.6.html#submit-requirements) [user-search](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#search-operators)